# Linux - I can't change permission NTFS partition for other read or execute

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, permissions

I've a problem that my NTFS partition that I can modify for the current user, but I can't change the permission for group or other to run files in this partition.

all files and folder in NTFS permission is: -rw------- 1

although i use change permision of partition name Working but it is still same permission
sudo chmod -R 755 /media/Working/

How can I fix this? because PHP script cannot glob() folder in partition Working, I think because don't have a permission to read.

Thanks

Comment: Try to change permisions from windowns machine that NTFS partition belongs to.
What do you want to run on linux that sits on ntfs partition?

Comment: I've change permission (sharing fullcontrol) on NTFS partition but this seem no difference.

Comment: try to remount it after you change permission.

Comment: I've restarted computer from share partition on Windows, it don't allow user on Linux have a chance.

Comment: Please set up "read for all" on windows partition from a windown PC. 
Is this windows belong to some active directory domain?

Answer (score 3):

look in file "/etc/fstab".
you will see there line like:

```
# /windows was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=703CD5D83CD59A04 /windows        ntfs    defaults,umask=077,gid=46 0       0
```

change the umask, and then do "umount" and after that "mount".

```
umount /windows
mount /windows
```

NTFS can't save UNIX type permissions, therefore you can apply only one umask to whole the FS.

Comment: Putting "NTFS doesn't have permissions" at the start of the answer would probably highlight what "the problem" is. +1

Answer (score 0):

From **man mount**, NTFS section:

> ```
>    uid=value, gid=value and umask=value
>           Set the file permission on the filesystem.  The umask value is given in octal.  By  default,  the  files
>           are owned by root and not readable by somebody else.
> ```

As was pointed by Dani-Br, you have to change the umask option of your NTFS partition. You can do this in this way:

```
mount /media/Working/ -oremount,umask=000
```

Of course, this will disappear after a reboot. In case you need a permanent solution, modify  your /etc/fstab and add the *umask=000* option just after the *defaults* option:

Comment: thanks Mr Victor but the permission is same.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the output of the command: "mount" ?

Comment: sudo mount /media/rasdaman/DWHouse/ -oremount,umask=000
sorry but nothing is output.

Comment: I mean, just type "mount" without parameters, and copy the output here, please.